# Playwright test library - parent element for selector

Tags: e2e-testing, playwright

please, how to get a parent element for a text selector by the Playwright E2E library.

Is better to modify the selector (it is string by something like `>> //:parent`) or evaluate the selector and then call the DOM element?

(The selector content is unknown)

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call `.$` to start searching from the element:

```
const elem = await page.$(anySelector)
const parent = await elem.$('xpath=..')
```

Doc: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-elementhandle#elementhandleselector

Answer (score 8):

Using the new `Locator` you can do:

```js
  const elementParent = await page.locator(`${childSelector} >> xpath=..`)
```

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator

https://playwright.dev/docs/selectors#xpath-selectors